# Type was not found 'ServerSocketConnectEvent'

Tags: sockets, actionscript-3, flash, mxmlc

I'm new with actionscript and want to create a socket server and listen to it, here is my code:

```
package
{ 
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.net.ServerSocket; 
  import flash.events;
  import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
  import flash.net.ServerSocket;
  import flash.net.Socket;

    public class one extends Sprite
    { 
        private static  var server:ServerSocket;
        private static  var client:Socket;

      public static function create() 
      {
        one.server = new ServerSocket();
        one.server.bind(8888);
        one.server.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, one.serverConnectHandler);
        one.server.listen();
      }

      public static function serverConnectHandler(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void 
      {
        var socket:Socket = e.socket;
        one.client = socket;
      }

      public static function send(param1:String)
      {
        one.client.writeUTFBytes(param1);
      }
    }
}
```

When I compile it using `mxmlc.exe -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true one.as` but get the error:

`C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\test program\one.as(23): col: 53 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ServerSocketConnectEvent.`

Same exact problem was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023816/1046-type-was-not-found-or-was-not-a-compile-time-constant-serversocketconnect) but Can't I somehow point to those libraries during compilation? The only solution is to build application form `adobe proffesional`? I'm little lost.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error: Look at your imports.

```
import flash.net.ServerSocket; 
import flash.events; //this is the problem
import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
```

You have use bad syntax when declaring the source paths of your imports. You should have received two errors, the second should say `Error 1172: Definition flash:events could not be found`.

```
import flash.events; //this is wrong syntax & does not load EVENTS Class (API)
import flash.events.*; //this is correct syntax to allow EVENTS Class
```

Start with `import flash.`+ `ClassName.` + `ABC;` ... where `ABC;` is a specific `Name;` or just use a generic `*;`

**Solution:**
So just replace `import flash.events;` with `import flash.events.*;` and it should work.

Comment: Even if I only have  `import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.net.ServerSocket; 
  import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
  import flash.net.ServerSocket;
  import flash.net.Socket;`
I still get same error, As I understand problem is in importing `ServerSocketConnectEvent`

Comment: Make sure you are compiling as AIR application (not just outputting an SWF to use in the browser), right? Using `flash.net.Socket` is fine for SWF (Flash Player plugin) but for  using `ServerSocket` it must be compiled as AIR (makes AS3 into native app for desktop or mobile). Incase you have only Flex SDK (I see the `mxmlc.exe`) then instead you should compile AIR apps with this: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

Comment: PS: Thinking about it, there is no `ServerSocket` in Flex so maybe that's why the Flex compiler complains, It should have also error'ed on the first `Server...` code (2nd import) but somehow it was okay with your imports until the 4th line. Also why import twice that `import flash.net.ServerSocket;`? Does removing one of those duplicates help?

Comment: No, I'll try what you suggested about AIR and share results

Comment: Stop press!! According to the docs... the Flex SDK includes the AIR SDK. Don't know if your Flex has the latest AIR though So still worth a  download. **(1)** Try this [basic tutorial](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc4c0afd1212601c9a36f-8000.html) instructions with your current Flex SDK. To compile use `amxmlc.exe` the "a" is for AIR compiling via Flex, see also article: [AIR compiling via Flex](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fa1.html).

Comment: **(2)** If you already got the AIR SDK (and not need any Flex components, you're shown code isn't using any of them) then try this [tutorial](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html) (alt version of [same tutorial](https://www.digimantra.com/air/creating-your-first-hello-world-application-in-adobe-air/)) to make sure everything compiles okay. Afterwards you can drop the web page display part and simply use your AS3 code instead. Use `ADL.exe` to preview/debug or use `ADT.exe` to compile an installable EXE of your code app.